# QGIS: Using Split Vector Layer how can I name the new files based on the unique value?

Tags: qgis, splitting, illustrator

I'm using Natural Earth 50m data and I want separate country shp layers so I can export to Illustrator. I can classify by `Long_Name` easily. I can `Split Vector Layer` on `Long_Name` easily. What I can't do is name the resulting files based on their unique `Long_Name` value. What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe run us through your exact steps when using `split vector layer`. I just tried it and it uses the attributes of the column the layer was split by.

Comment: Open `Select Vector Layer` in `Processing Toolbox`.Input layer is my correct layer. Change the `Unique ID Field` to `Name_Long`. Select my appropriate `Output Directory`

Result: A folder full of files named `NAME_LONG_0` through `NAME_LONG_264`

Comment: And how does the output not satisfy your needs?

Comment: I need to retain the unique `NAME_LONG` value. Because I need Illustrator layers named "Afghanistan" not `NAME_LONG_264`. I have thought about re-naming, but I can't seem to batch that OR parse the file (even manually) to extract the name.

Comment: Have you verified that the column actually holds the country names, and not the IDs?

Comment: Yes. `NAME_LONG` definitely holds names. I'm browsing the attributes table to do manual extractions now.

Comment: I tried running the tool with a layer with 487 features, all split layers were named correctly. Maybe your file path is too long? Can you provide a link to your data?

Comment: I'm using the shp file inside of [this zip from Natural Earth Data](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/50m/cultural/ne_50m_admin_0_map_units.zip)

Comment: Sorry, you must be doing something wrong. I tried with your data and the `NAME_LONG` field and got 264 geopackages named like the corresponding features.

Comment: That is exciting but also infuriating. Mac or PC? Can you walk me through your steps? Any different than mine?

Comment: PC, Win10, working on a local drive only 3 folders "deep".

Comment: I tried with a folder directly in my user folder. Are you exporting to SHP files? Are the output files named correctly or is the correct name only the one that shows up when it's brought back in?

Comment: I'm exporting geopackages, but I haven't seen any option to change the export. Output files are named "NAME_LONG_country"

Comment: Can you possibly show me a screenshot of your Split Vector Layer window?

Comment: QGIS-Version: 3.10.5-A Coruña
QGIS-Codeversion: 984615fe1e
Qt-Version: 5.11.2
GDAL-Version: 3.0.4
GEOS-Version: 3.8.1-CAPI-1.13.3
PROJ-Version: Rel. 6.3.1, February 10th, 2020
Verarbeite Algorithmus…
Algorithmus Vektorlayer teilen startet…
Eingabeparameter:
{ 'FIELD' : 'NAME_LONG', 'INPUT' : 'C:/Users/Erik/Downloads/ne_50m_admin_0_map_units.shp', 'OUTPUT' : 'C:\\Users\\Erik\\Documents\\test' }

Erzeuge Layer: C:\Users\Erik\Documents\test\NAME_LONG_Dominican Republic.gpkg
1 Objekte zu Layer hinzugefügt
Erzeuge Layer: C:\Users\Erik\Documents\test\NAME_LONG_Namibia.gpkg

Comment: oh no...it was my QGIS version. Worked perfectly in 3.10 but I had grabbed 3.14

Comment: You may consider creating a bug report. And I'd vote to close the question, since it seems to be a bug and no problem we can solve here.

Answer (score 1):

Just download the new version. Been cracking my head as well why the values are not unique.
3.16 is the latest. I was using 3.14 before.