# Using Split vector Layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, split-by-attribute

I am trying to split a vector file using an attribute value and wants to name the each created output as the name in the attribute field. I am being able to split the vector layer but it is giving names by default to each of the file, i wants it to be specifically with the name in the attribute table. Suppose i have a field in attribute table title as NAMES and values in it as:

ABC

DEF

GHI

JKL

MNO

so i want it each to be split out and saved as NAMES_ABC, NAMES_DEF, NAMES_GHI, NAMES_JKL and so on

instead i am getting the names as NAMES_0, NAMES_1,NAMES_2, NAMES_3 and so on

Comment: Please specify which tool you're using, which settings in this tool, and which QGIS you're working with.

Comment: The tool is Split Vector Layer,  It can be found in Processing Toolbox --> Vector general --> Split Vector Layer

Comment: You can do this with some pyqgis code. Can you add a screenshot showing the attribute table?

Comment: This is perfectly possible using QGIS 3.10, while 3.14 throws an error/gives only numbers. We had the same issue a few days back:https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/370390/qgis-using-split-vector-layer-how-can-i-name-the-new-files-based-on-the-unique?noredirect=1#comment604933_370390

Comment: Thanks to all as i tried QGIS 3.10 it worked out. Hoping that this bug will be removed soon by QGIS community

Answer (score 2):

There was a [pull request](https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/pull/37298)  to implement that functionality which just got merged into QGIS-master, so with the next release it should be included.

If you do not want to wait for the next release, you have to install QGIS 1.8 an install the plugin "ShapefileSplitter". It does exactly what you want to achieve